# Create subfolder with same name as parent and move files into it

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have folders as below. I want to create subdirectory with same name and move only few of the files into sub directory

Input

```
 Parent

   folder1/a.txt
   folder1/b.txt
   folder2/a.txt
   folder2/b.txt
   folder3/a.txt
   folder3/b.txt 


Output

  Parent

  folder1/folder1/a.txt
  folder1/b.txt
  folder2/folder2/a.txt
  folder2/b.txt
  folder3/folder3/a.txt
  folder3/b.txt
```

I tried this , but this is working only for files not folders

```
       for file in *; do dir=$(echo $file | cut -d. -f1); mkdir -p $dir; mv $file $dir; done
```

Comment: Can you clarify? The question is tagged as linux, but the link in the question is one for batch.

Comment: The syntax in the linked question is for Microsoft Windows, not Linux.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am looking for a linux solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell is bash, you can run the following:

```
for file in */a.txt ; do 
    dir=${file%/a.txt}
    mkdir "$dir/$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir/$dir"
done
```

It uses the *parameter expansion* to remove the `/a.txt` from the file name which only leaves the directory name in `$dir`.

Comment: Thanks..Will this work if i have multiple files ending in *a.txt that has to be moved into subfolders?

Comment: Not without a modification.